# How to select an aggregated column from a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

`df = df.groupby(F.upper(F.col('count'))).agg({'totalvis.age':'avg'}).show()` creates `avg(totalvis.age AS` age`)` column.

I want to use another aggregate function to select max of the newly created column, but there is an issue with column name not being resolvable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this syntax below to assign a column alias to the aggregation:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.groupby(F.upper(F.col('county'))).agg(F.avg('totalvisitor.age').alias('age_avg'))
```

Then you can select the maximum as `df2.select(F.max('age_avg'))`.

PS Note that in the code you provided in the question, you have overwritten `df` with `None` after calling

```
df = df.(...).show()
```

because `df.show()` returns `None`.

Comment: Thanks mck, how would i select the county for max age avg?

Comment: @RaviShastri you can do `df3 = df2.filter(F.col('age_avg') == df2.select(F.max('age_avg')).head()[0])`